# Arbitrary precision for non-integers

Tags: math, haskell

Haskell has a built-in `Integer` type, which handles arbitrary-precision integers. There is also `Rational`, which is an arbitrary-precision fraction. But arithmetic on such things requires finding a common denominator, and then cancelling the result down to least terms.

What if I wanted to do floating-point arithmetic with (say) 100 bits of precision in the mantissa? How would I do that?

I see there's a `Data.Fixed` module, but that seems to provide a handful of custom-written types with fixed precision. What I want is something where I can dynamically increase or decrease precision at run-time, according to how much accuracy is required for each task.

PS. I'm not looking for *decimal* arithmetic, although I suppose it would be interesting to know whether that's available somewhere...

Comment: you can work with Rational and use [`approxRational`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Ratio.html#v:approxRational) from time to time to keep it in check.

Comment: Rational numbers should do everything you need, never losing precision, in a self contained library. Is the trouble with reading/writing out Rationals in a human readable format (ie. decimal expansion)?

Answer (score 4):

Try `Data.Number.CReal` from the [numbers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers) package.  It gives you the precision you ask for when converting to a string.

Comment: I'm not really interested in converting to a string; I'm interested in tuning arithmetic precision to do performance / accuracy tradeoffs.

Comment: Well, `CReal` isn't very performant.  But it adapts the precision dynamically to what is needed.  Presumably you are using your numbers for something in the end.

Comment: Mandelbrot generator. So all I'm doing is counting how many iterations it takes for a certain inequality to be met.

Comment: I don't think `CReal` is for you then.  It's not very efficient, and comparison is only semi-decidable for real numbers.

Comment: If you use CReal, you can avoid undecidability just by replacing "abs z \`compare\` threshold" with "abs (imagPart z * realPart z) \`compare\` (threshold * threshold)"

Comment: @JeremyList I don't see how that avoids undecidability.

Comment: @augustss Comparison is decidable for rational numbers, and the square root used in "abs" of a complex number is the only source of irrational numbers in a mandelbrot set generator.

Answer (score 0):

How about http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-2009.8.9/docs/Data-Number-BigFloat.html ? In this BigFloat data type you choose precision on your own. I know it's decimal, but maybe you can easily change it to binary

Comment: That's compile-time, but... perhaps a good use case for existentials. More problematic though for this question, it's not a floating-point type at all, despite the name.